# Use a variable in file path in .vbs

Tags: variables, vbscript

Is it possible to usa variable in a path in .vbs. My basic situation is I have a vbs script that will often be run on a computer with one person logged in and run by an admin with a completely different user name (assume the file will be right clicked and "Run As").

The script edits an ini file that is located in the user directory for the person logged in. I know in batch I could simply insert the variable `"C:\Users\%Logger%\AppData\Local\stat.ini"` and the variable would be replaced. But I can't do this in .vbs. My script thus far. Or look at the bulk of it in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423316/search-and-edit-a-file-with-a-batch-file).

```
Dim blnRes: blnRes = 0
Dim strOld, strNew, logger
strOld = "frogg"
strNew = "frog"
logger = Inputbox("What is your Domain ID exactly as entered when you log into this machine?","Domain ID")

On Error Resume Next
Call update("C:\Users\logger\AppData\Local\stat.ini", strOld, strNew)
blnRes = blnRes Or (Err.Number = 0): Err.Clear
```

Is there some way I can flag `logger` as a variable, or is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're after correctly, you're either going to need to do a string concatenation where you build a string like `"string part 1" & logger & "string part 2"` or use the replace function to replace `%Logger%` (e.g. `Replace(templateString, "%Logger%", logger)`) with your logger variable. There's not a direct equivalent to the `%1` sort of format used in batch files.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you meant a script variable. Try this:

```
logger = Inputbox("What is ID?","Domain ID")
Call update("C:\Users\"& logger &"\AppData\Local\stat.ini", strOld, strNew)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use command line arguments with vbs.  See the following technet site:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156618.aspx

using the example vbs at the bottom, you can have Ping.vbs reply based on the computer name entered after the script name when its called  (C:\scripts\Ping.vbs Hostname)

Here's more info on WScript.Aurguments
https://www.google.com/search?q=WScript.Arguments&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-Address&ie=&oe=

---

```
'Ping.vbs:
Dim arArguments, strArgument
Set arArguments = WScript.Arguments
WScript.Echo WScript.Arguments.Count
For Each strArgument in arArguments
If Ping(strArgument) Then
    WScript.Echo strArgument & " is available."
Else
    WScript.Echo strArgument & " is not available."
End If  
Next 
Function Ping( myHostName )
Dim colPingResults, objPingResult, strQuery
strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PingStatus WHERE Address = '" & myHostName & "'"
Set colPingResults = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2").ExecQuery( strQuery )
For Each objPingResult In colPingResults
    If Not IsObject( objPingResult ) Then
        Ping = False
    ElseIf objPingResult.StatusCode = 0 Then
        Ping = True
    Else
        Ping = False
    End If
Next
Set colPingResults = Nothing
End Function
```

---

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
Dim fs, ws, Path
Set ws = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
Path = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%UserProfile%\testfile.txt" )
ws = Nothing
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fs.CreateTextFile (Path, True)
f.WriteLine("This is a test")
f.Close()
f = Nothing
```

Don't assume "C:\Users" will be valid on every system. There are times when you may want to use a different location for user profiles.  I also looked at the %AppData% environment variable, but in my case that pointed to AppData\Roaming, and you want AppData\Local.

Comment: C:\Users isn't valid on every system, in our environment we have XP which uses documents and settings and a couple of sites that store the user profiles on a server. I was planning on determining the OS and conditionally running a line with a directory. I went ahead and tested the script anyway and it runs into the same issue, it calls the user profile of whomever ran the file. I will edit the post to make it more clear, sorry about that.