# Append or put variable within string in vbscript?

Tags: string, variables, vbscript, quote

I am wanting to include the variable **domainUser** within the quoted command sent to the commandline but I am not having any luck. What I am trying to accomplish is to create a log file titled with their domain name but I keep getting errors or just getting a txt file with no title.

```
Dim domainUser
domainUser = Example123

objInParam.Properties_.Item("CommandLine") = "cmd /c ECHO Test >> c:\UserLogs\"""domainUser""".txt"
```

So line 4 would be read like this (or whatever domain user I put in on line 2)...

```
objInParam.Properties_.Item("CommandLine") = "cmd /c ECHO Test >> c:\UserLogs\Example123.txt"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to launch bat file form VBScript if path contains a space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254375/not-able-to-launch-bat-file-form-vbscript-if-path-contains-a-space)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [About using Double quotes in Vbscript - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770599/about-using-double-quotes-in-vbscript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use a variable in file path in .vbs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7534459/692942)

Comment: Take your pick and that's just a small selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need concatenation to splice a variable's content into a string and double double quotes to put double quotes into it:

```
>> Dim domainUser
>> domainUser = "Example123"
>> Dim cmd
>> cmd = "cmd /c ECHO Test >> ""c:\UserLogs\" & domainUser &  ".txt"""
>> WScript.Echo cmd
>>
cmd /c ECHO Test >> "c:\UserLogs\Example123.txt"
```