# In CATIA I trying to add some propertıes from parameter but I can't add my part name

Tags: vbscript, catia

I saved a macro and edited it. It looks like this:

```
Language="VBSCRIPT"

Sub CATMain()

Set partDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument

Set part1 = partDocument1.Part

Set relations1 = part1.Relations

Set parameters1 = part1.Parameters

Set strParam1 = parameters1.Item("03_019_OP40-15_UPPER_TRIM_STEEL\Properties\FCA_DETAIL_NO")

Set formula1 = relations1.CreateFormula("Formula.10", "", strParam1, "FCA_NAMING ")

formula1.Rename "Formula.10"

End Sub
```

In here you can see name of part which is 03_019_OP40-15_UPPER_TRIM_STEEL

But other parts name also different. So I want to make it reads from parts name but I don't have any idea how to make it.

```
"03_019_OP40-15_UPPER_TRIM_STEEL\Properties\FCA_DETAIL_NO"
```

I tried something like this but not worked.

```
Set strParam1 = parameters1.Item("part1.Name\Properties\FCA_NAMING")
```

It's not windows road or etc It's Catia tree part name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use a variable in file path in .vbs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7534459)

Comment: VBScript does not support string interpolation out of the box, would recommend looking through the [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/t0aew7h6(v=vs.84)) or an online tutorial to get the basics of string and variable concatenation.

Comment: I don't know Catia but based on your example try this line - `Set strParam1 = parameters1.Item(part1.Name & "\Properties\FCA_DETAIL_NO")`.

Comment: You could also use `GetNameToUseInRelation` of the parameter collection to get the correct string.

Comment: @user692942 this worked sir thank you so much: Set strParam1 = parameters1.Item(part1.Name & "\Properties\FCA_DETAIL_NO")

Comment: @Shrotter Hey Mr. how can I use this GetNameToUseInRelation can you give a small example?

Comment: @YunusMertAŞKIN you may have a look onto https://v5vb.wordpress.com/2010/05/24/developing-names-in-product-relations/

Comment: @YunusMertAŞKIN Just be aware that the link Shrotter is providing is using VBA not VBScript so the syntax will be a little different.